# Which one is faster in processing and conversion int.Parse(), int.TryParse(), Convert.Int32()

Tags: c#, .net

Which one is faster, powerfull and reliable. And why ?

```
int.Parse()
int.TryParse()
Convert.ToInt32()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go [read this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151215225344/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx) ("Performance Profiling Parse vs. TryParse vs. ConvertTo") for much add'l info.

If you are unsure if the string is parsable, then `int.TryParse()` will be MUCH faster than either of the others and catching the exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

`Convert.Int32()` calls `Int32.Parse()` with an extra check for null, <strike>so `Int32.Parse()` might be a tad faster.</strike> which is why `Convert.Int32()` will be faster (it catches the null before `Int32.Parse()` has to deal with it).

`Int32.Parse()` calls `Number.ParseInt32()` internally which throws Exceptions when a number can't be parsed.

`Int32.TryParse()` calls `Number.TryParseInt32()` internally which has similar code to `Number.ParseInt32()` but instead of throwing Exceptions it simply returns false...which introduces less overhead.

Considering all those variables, my guess would be that `Int32.TryParse()` will give you the fastest results for non-null values. If there's a chance the majority of the calls could contain nulls, I would say `Convert.Int32()` would perform better.

...all that brought to you by the power of .NET Reflector.

Comment: +1, but regarding "so Int32.Parse() might be a tad faster": I guess you won't be able to measure the null-check. In fact it will be slower if your input is `null` according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx: "The difference is, as we guessed, in the exception handling code. That is why Convert was faster then Parse as Convert handles the null string in the bad data set without throwing an exception."

Comment: @0xA3 Updated my answer to reflect the comment. Thanks for the catch (and reference).

Answer (score 0):

Both `int.Parse` and `Convert.Int32` internally call `int.TryParse`, so performance differences between them should be trivial. `TryParse` is the most versatile in that it allows you to decide whether or not to throw an exception, but otherwise there is no difference between these methods.

Comment: Actually, if you take a look in Reflector, int.Parse calls Number.ParseInt32 internally...it never calls int.TryParse.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I was about to go open up some source code, but I'll take your info as confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToInt32(string) calls Int32.Parse(string).

However, if you use Int32.Parse (or the equivalent int.Parse), you can specify globalization and formatting used when parsing.

Int.Parse will be faster since it doesn't do a try/catch.

Int.TryParse is more reliable and won't throw an error if you don't pass it a non-convertible value.

Comment: Actually, if you take a look in Reflector, int.Parse calls Number.ParseInt32 internally...it never calls int.TryParse

Comment: @Ed: Who says TryParse has to be implemented in terms of Parse, and not the other way around?

Comment: This somewhat contradicts what is written in the benchmark referenced by Jaxidian. `int.Parse` won't be faster according to that.

Comment: @Ed There is no try/catch in TryParse either. If you look at the internal code being called, where Parse would throw an Exception TryParse simply returns false. Throwing an Exception adds more overhead, thus slowing things down.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use

```
int.Parse(...)
```

if I have a string as a source and

```
Convert.ToInt32(...)
```

if I have a valueType (double, decimal) as a source, because otherwise I had to cast it to strings and deal with the local culture.

Comment: I use `int.Parse` if I want an exception thrown on a string that I'm parsing (i.e. an API that expects a page number or something as a querystring parameter). I use `int.TryParse` on a string that I'm parsing if I want to handle it right then and there. I use `Convert.ToInt32` if it's not a string (whether it's a decimal, an int boxed in an object, or whatever). So I'm on page with you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I find that the answer depends on the context.

If I'm converting (for example) a `DataRow` to an object, I'll have lots of `Convert.ToXXX` calls, so I would use `Convert.ToInt32` because that is consistent with the other statements around that conversion.

In other situations, if I want to throw an exception when the string does not parse (fail-fast) I'll use `int.Parse`, because that throws the exception for me, and `int.TryParse` tends to generate uglier code (I've never been a fan of out parameters)

And if I just want to specify some default value if the string does not parse, I'll use `int.TryParse`, because otherwise, I'll have to handle the exception myself, and that is both expensive and ugly.

However, unless you are calling the parsing site billions of times, I would be surprised to see a discernible time difference between any of the three formats, so I would prefer a more readable piece of code, over a marginally faster variant.