# which version of the code below is right?

Tags: c#

Hi I found this function in a utilities code file:

**Version 1:**

```
public static bool IsValidLong(string strLong)
{
    bool result = true;
    try
    {
        long tmp = long.Parse(strLong);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to replace this (and validators for other types) with following:

**Version 2:**

```
public static bool IsValidLong(string strLong)
{
    long l;
    return long.TryParse(strLong, out l);
}
```

which version is better and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first exists because the 2nd didn't at one point ([`Int64.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h.aspx) was added in .Net 2.0)...use the second version, why not take advantage of the features the framework adds in the newer releases if they're available to you? :)

The second is much clearer, leaner and more maintinable...I'd say it's a much better approach... it just wasn't available before.

Also, I believe `TryParse()` doesn't actually throw any exception internally, so it would be slower in a successful parse, but much quicker/less expensive than throwing an exception in the case of a failed parse.

Comment: thanks @Nick I don't thing the code is that old. It was written not before .Net 2.0

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - It's likely the programmer just didn't know about `.TryParse()` at the time then.

Comment: Why would `TryParse` be slower? In fact, that is not the case; for a successful parse both are equally fast. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922565/which-one-is-faster-in-processing-and-conversion-int-parse-int-tryparse-con/2922629#2922629 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx. When it comes to performance it is usually better not to believe as it is so easy to be wrong... ;-) But it is correct that `TryParse` does not throw exceptions internally so that it will be significantly faster on erroneous input.

Comment: @0xA3: There is some overhead to TryParse for that exception-less handling, you can run a simple loop to test this. I ran 10,000,000 iterations of TryParse vs Parse in a simple linqpad test here, TryPrase: **1249-1280ms** over 10 tests, Parse: **1143-1152ms** over the same 10 tests.  Try it yourself: http://pastebin.com/AUQ6RpF8

Comment: When I ran you sample I didn't see a significant difference. One possible explanation could be that LinqPad doesn't optimize the code as well as the C#/JIT compilers do.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second one since both do same and second one is less code.

Answer (score 1):

In the second version the FW is encapsulating the behaviour in the first version for you.  I would say that the two examples are equivalent but I would say the code in the second example is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

version 2 is better, wrap code in a try/catch block will affect performance, I think the TryParse() implementation will not use this approach.