# Parse int[] from "1,2,3"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, arrays

I have a multiselect dropdown called ID that submits ID=1,2,3 which I need parsed into an integer array to do a Contains() on in a filter method. At the moment I use:

```
string[] ids = Request["ID"].Split(',');
```

Which I don't really like because its slower to compare string than int. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Request["ID"].Split(',').Select(x=>int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Of course, this will throw if any of the resulting numeric strings are not "parseable" (does such a word exist?).

Comment: you can simplify, btw; `Request["ID"].Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`, or even `Array.ConvertAll(Request["ID"].Split(','), int.Parse)`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many times you will look up in the array if converting to ints are faster or the string comparison is faster.

```
HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(from s in Request["ID"].Split(',')
                                    select int.Parse(s));
```

But probably the fastest if you have many id:s will be to create a `HashSet<string>`:

```
HashSet<string> = new HashSet<string>(string[] ids = Request["ID"].Split(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] ids = Request["ID"].Split(',').Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
```

Comment: or `.Select(Convert.ToInt32)`

Comment: @Random: +1 Yup, that's even more concise.  I'll change the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
string[] arr = Request["ID"].Split(',')
```

Then:

```
Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => Int32.Parse(s));
Array.ConvertAll(arr, Int32.Parse);

arr.Select(s => Int32.Parse(s));
arr.Select(Int32.Parse);
```

Then:

```
new HashSet<int>(result);
```

(the most fast container to perform `Contains()`)

See also:

- [Convert string[] to int[] in one string of code using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-string-of-code-using-linq)
- [Which one is faster in processing and conversion int.Parse(), int.TryParse(), Convert.Int32()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922565/which-one-is-faster-in-processing-and-conversion-int-parse-int-tryparse-con)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have linq, you can:

```
string[] ids = Request["ID"].Split(',');
int[] items = new int[ids.Length];
for(int i = 0; i<ids.Length; i++)
{
  items[i] = int.Parse(ids[i]);
}
```

Comment: For info, those last 4 lines are just: `int[] items = Array.ConvertAll(ids, int.Parse);`

Comment: Excellent, moving on for sigma scan!  (Buzz Lightyear).